# Simple BrowserComponent crashes the application

Tags: java, codenameone

This is my first app developed in CodeName One. It is basically a WebView (`BrowserComponent`) with some options (back, forward, load url etc)... The problem is that after building and starting the app in the simulation mode, it crashes after a bit:

```
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.3+7) (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x8ba319]
```

The code is:

```
Form hi = new Form("Browser", new BorderLayout());
BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
browser.setURL("http://html5test.com/");
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
```

Opening another URL than `html5test.com` does not crash the application instantly, but after navigating on pages...

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

*PS: I tried to build the app for android and it seems to be working fine on my phone... The problem is that if it crashes on my computer, I am unsure if the app is stable or not.*

Comment: Could it be a problem related to OpenJDK 11? Could you try the same code with Oracle Java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in the simulator we use the pretty awful JavaFX browser component. When running everywhere else (other than Desktop builds) we use the native browser for that platform which is always way better. So you would see compatibility and stability issues.

Unfortunately there is no stable free alternative to JavaFXs browser component. Hence the stability/quality issues in the simulator are a pain but they are no indication of the behavior on the device.